# how to append the new content, with the exiting content?

Tags: jquery, ajax

My tag is look like this

```
  <ul>
     <li data-newsid="1">News One</li>
     <li data-newsid="2">News Two</li>
     <li data-newsid="3">News Three</li>
     <li data-newsid="4">News Four</li>
     <li data-newsid="5">News Five</li>
</ul>
```

**i loaded the data via jquery ajax Top Five news**

when administrator add new data **"News Six"**, it should append with the existing, news via ajax....

**Make sure that, i dont want to re-append all the news... with the existing list of news, "News Six" should be append**

```
     <ul>
         <li data-newsid="1">News One</li>
         <li data-newsid="2">News Two</li>
         <li data-newsid="3">News Three</li>
         <li data-newsid="4">News Four</li>
         <li data-newsid="5">News Five</li>
         <li data-newsid="6">News Six </li>
         etc....
    </ul>
```

thanks you....

Comment: how is your ajax response looks like

Comment: Ajax response is JSON.... Id, name

Comment: share your script which is generating the `li` from the json

Comment: something like `if ($('li[data-newsid="' + id + '"]').length == 0) {
    $('ul').append('<li data-newsid="' + id + '">...</li>')
}`

Comment: thanks for your logic.... its more use ful...

Comment: If you can post a fiddle, I could provide a complete solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use append for that:

```
 $('ul').append('<li data-newsid="'+id+'">'+news+'</li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$("ul").append('<li data-newsid="'+id+'">'+name+'</li>');
```

Note: I assume you have `id` and `name` variables, you can change it with your JSON variables..